# Denver SHP-102 successfully flashed but only slow blinking

Tags: iot, esphome

I have made my first attempt using tuya-cloudcutter to install the firmware ESPHome-Kickstart-v23.08.29_bk7231n_app.ota.ug.bin in my Denver SHP-102, and I managed to get to the web page of the device (however, in case is important: I could not make it join my wifi from there). Then, I have taken the config file from [esphome](https://devices.esphome.io/devices/Denver-SHP-102), as is the exact same device, and I have generated a firmware, esphome_2023.12.8_generic-bk7231n-qfn32-tuya_bk7231n_lt1.4.1.uf2, which I have uploaded OTA through that same web page. The page has returned as a successful update.

Now I get the plug in its slow blinking mode indefinitely (as if it was looking for the AP to join the wifi, but never switches back to the fallback AP), and this triggers some questions:

```
1. have I bricked it?
2. Can I fix this situation?
3. could I have been installed directly the firmware I generated without going first through that ESPHome-Kickstart?
```

Thank you very much for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: the reason for the device blinking is that it had a cycle period of 1 s to switch between current and voltage measuring. Other than that, and that I did not check the MAC properly to get the assigned IP address, all is good. Thank you, anyway!